# Android: App crashes while showing custom listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to show my database in custom listview  but everytime I run that activity, my app stops unfortunately. Please have a look at my code and help me out.
This is my activity in which I'm trying to extract data from the table which is selected in the drop down list and hence display it in the custom listview.

```
package com.example.aas.advancedattendancesystem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import model_class.Attendance_database;
import model_class.Attendance_database_handler;

import static com.example.aas.advancedattendancesystem.R.id.dropdown;
import static com.example.aas.advancedattendancesystem.R.id.listshow;

public class Show_databases extends AppCompatActivity {

private Attendance_database_handler adh;
private ArrayList<Attendance_database> dblist = new ArrayList<>();
private CustomArrayAdapter caa;
private ListView lvshow;
private Spinner dropdown;
String[] items = new String[]{"CSE7A"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_icon);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#3BB9FF'>Attendance </font>"));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_databases);

    lvshow=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listshow);
    dropdown=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dropdown);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);


    dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            refreshData(selected);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}


    private void refreshData(String selected) {
       try {
           dblist.clear();
           adh = new Attendance_database_handler(getApplicationContext());
           ArrayList<Attendance_database> listFromDB;
           listFromDB= adh.getAttendance_list(selected);

           for (int i = 0; i < listFromDB.size(); i++) {

               Integer roll = listFromDB.get(i).getRoll();
               String name = listFromDB.get(i).getStudent_name();

               Attendance_database mylist = new Attendance_database();
               mylist.setRoll(roll);
               mylist.setStudent_name(name);

               dblist.add(mylist);
           }
           adh.close();

           caa = new CustomArrayAdapter(Show_databases.this, R.layout.custom_listview, dblist);
           lvshow.setAdapter(caa);
           caa.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }catch (Exception e){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }
}
```

This is my database handler

```
    package model_class;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import static model_class.Constants.ROLL;
    import static model_class.Constants.STUDENT_NAME;
    import static model_class.Constants.TABLE_NAME;


    public class Attendance_database_handler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//private final ArrayList<Attendance_database> attendance_list=new ArrayList<>();

public Attendance_database_handler(Context context) {
    super(context,Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
    Log.v("OnUpgrade","Dropping the table");
    onCreate(db);

}

public void addRecord(Attendance_database adb){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+
            adb.getClass_name()+"("+
            ROLL+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
            STUDENT_NAME+" TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();


    values.put(ROLL,adb.getRoll());
    values.put(STUDENT_NAME,adb.getStudent_name());

    db.insert(adb.getClass_name(),null,values);
    db.close();
}

public ArrayList<Attendance_database> getAttendance_list(String selected) {

    //attendance_list.clear();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + selected;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
    ArrayList<Attendance_database> attendance_list = new ArrayList<>();
    //loop through cursor

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            Attendance_database myList = new Attendance_database();

            myList.setRoll(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ROLL)));
            myList.setStudent_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(STUDENT_NAME)));

            attendance_list.add(myList);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return attendance_list;

}

}
```

This is the class which has all the parameters which I want in my table.

```
package model_class;

public class Constants {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME="db_name";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=8;
public static final String TABLE_NAME="tb_name";
public static final String STUDENT_NAME="st_name";
public static final String ROLL="st_roll";
}
```

This is my custom array adapter

```
package com.example.aas.advancedattendancesystem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import model_class.Attendance_database;

public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Attendance_database> {

private ArrayList<Attendance_database> alist = new ArrayList<>();
Activity activity;
int layoutResource;
Attendance_database adb;


public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity act, int resource, ArrayList<Attendance_database> data) {
    super(act, resource, data);
    activity = act;
    layoutResource = resource;
    alist = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return alist.size();
}

@Override
public Attendance_database getItem(int position) {
    return  alist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null || (view.getTag())==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.roll= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvroll);
        holder.name= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder=(ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.mylist=getItem(position);
    holder.roll.setText(holder.mylist.getRoll());
    holder.name.setText(holder.mylist.getStudent_name());
    return view;
}


class ViewHolder{
Attendance_database mylist;
TextView roll;
TextView name;
}}
```

Please help. I'm not able to figure out what is wrong. Thank you in advance :)

LOGCAT:

```
07-12 17:09:49.168 8600-8600/com.example.aas.advancedattendancesystem 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: com.example.aas.advancedattendancesystem, PID: 8600
                                                                                        android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
                                                                                            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4554)
                                                                                        at com.example.aas.advancedattendancesystem.CustomArrayAdapter.getView(CustomArrayAdapter.java:74)
                                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2362)
                                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
                                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
                                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
                                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1716)
                                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2161)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I think the error is in customArrayAdapter but I'm not able to figure out exactly where

Comment: Please add the crash logs.

Comment: Plus you should use a BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter.

Comment: post you error logs

Comment: I have added the logcat . Please have a look